# BinarySearch. Print out the elements that are compared to the target?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search

I'm struggling with this textbook problem. What modification would I have to do the BinarySearch function so that it prints out the sequence of array elements that are compared to the target?

```
public class BinarySearch {

public static int binarySearch(int[] A, int p, int r, int target) {
   int q;
   if(p > r) {
      return -1;
   }else {
      q = (p + r)/2;
      if(target == A[q]) {
         return q;
      } else if (target < A[q]) {
          return binarySearch(A, p, q-1, target);
      } else {
          return binarySearch(A, q+1, r, target);
      }
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

   System.out.println(binarySearch(B, 0, B.length-1, 7));
   System.out.println(binartSearch(B, 0, B.length-1, 2));
   System.out.println(binarySearch(B, 0, B.length-1, 11));
  }
}
```

Comment: you misspelled `binarySearch`  here `System.out.println(binartSearch(B, 0, B.length-1, 2));` while printing.Rest of the code looks ok

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the elements that are compared to the target then simply add a print statement before the comparison in your method `binarySearch`:

```
q = (p + r)/2;
System.out.print(A[q]+" ");  //  <---- here
if(target == A[q]) {
    System.out.print("-> "); //  <---- here
    return q;
}
```

Also you can add `System.out.print("-> ");` for better representation ,if the target not found

```
if(p > r) {
   System.out.print("-> "); // <-- here
   return -1;
}
```

Here the numbers before the arrow are the elements with which the target is compared,and after arrow is the return value of method.

**Output:**

```
5 8 6 7 -> 6
5 2 -> 1
5 8 9 10 -> -1
```